# Unable to Build from Source and Install IDJC 0.8.17 in Ubuntu Focal

Tags: 20.04, gtk

Unable to Build from Source and Install IDJC 0.8.17 in Ubuntu Focal.  It Calls for two dependancies which are now unavailable.

python-gtk2-dev  and  python-mutagen

Is there a way around this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can download packages [from 19.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/idjc) and install them manually:

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/idjc
cd ~/Downloads/idjc

wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-6_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-irc/python-irc_8.5.3+dfsg-4_all.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mutagen/python-mutagen_1.40.0-2_all.deb
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/i/idjc/idjc_0.8.17-1build1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
```

and use it.